# Latest Google Angular CDN doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-cdn

Following is the demo page using google angular js cdn:

```
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="TextController">
        <p>{{mytext}}</p>
    </body>
    <script>
        function TextController($scope) {
            $scope.mytext = "hello world";
        }
    </script>
    </html>
```

and I used the latest google angular js cdn.

It gives a series of errors as follows:

```
angular.js:13708 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/ng/areq?p0=TextController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
at Error (native)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:6:412
at sb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:22:508)
at Qa (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:23:78)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:89:273
at ag (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:72:353)
at m (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:64:218)
at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:58:481)
at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:58:498)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:58:119(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13708
```

However when I changed the version of angular to `1.0.1`. The page is shown properly.

Does the new version made any change?

Comment: What errors did you get? 1.0.1 and 1.5.7 are very different.

Comment: @ShuheiKagawa Edited.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know from which version but the controller must be registered to de app.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('TextController', TextController);
```

Also you need an app priveder.

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

Comment: but the author has no "app" variable on her code...

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the module and the controller... there are no problem with cdn:

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

and

```
<script>
    angular.module('app', []).controller('TextController', TextController);
    ...
```

look this jsbin: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nekofo/edit?html,output)